# Select single row from multiple duplicate rows with value 1 SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need only one row from multiple duplicate rows but the value should not missed in others fields

Current table:

```
Name      ABC   XYZ APT STA ZIP
--------------------------------
Computer    0   0   0   0   0
Computer    0   0   0   1   0
Computer    0   0   0   0   0
Computer    1   0   0   0   0
Computer    0   0   0   0   0
```

Result I want:

```
Name      ABC   XYZ APT STA ZIP
-------------------------------- 
Computer    1   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: So, `max()` of each column?

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`?

Comment: What is your criteria for a ***duplicate***? Is it the same `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many already suggested, it is a trivial task.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _Name VARCHAR(20), ABC INT, XYZ INT, APT INT, STA INT, ZIP INT);
INSERT @tbl (_Name, ABC, XYZ, APT, STA, ZIP) VALUES
('Computer', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('Computer', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
('Computer', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('Computer', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('Computer', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT _Name, MAX(ABC) ABC, MAX(XYZ) XYZ, MAX(APT) APT, MAX(STA) STA, MAX(ZIP) ZIP
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY _Name;
```

**Output**

| _Name | ABC | XYZ | APT | STA | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |